# Switch bounce vs LC Spike Voltage

Tags: voltage, switches, transient, debounce

For my EE lab, our professor wants us to show switch bounce, and then eliminate it using hardware, and software debouncing.

However, I seem to be stuck on finding the switch bounce in the first place. Attached is a snapshot of my scope when the pushbutton switch is triggered. To my untrained eye I can't be sure if what I am seeing is actually even switch bounce, or simply transient LC-voltages. How do I tell the difference, and/or is it just possible that the pushbutton I used has almost no bounce?

[image]

*Edit* Attached circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fybnCp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's just LC ringing as you suspect, definitely not switch bounce. Try zooming out, switch bounce will be closer to a millisecond time frame.

Comment: Maybe your switch is too good. Try a different switch and also just try touching wires together if you want to see bad bouncing.

Comment: Is it a spring loaded (*toggle* switch or push button) with hysteresis?  These are kind that are undamped with bounce 0.5~10 ms for microswitches when closed.

Comment: I also ran into this issue in school. Try to get the biggest, nastiest power switch you can find (perhaps from an old vehicle or power tool), and test that.

Answer (score 1):

Now you know what a series underdamped 2nd order effect looks like.

2nd order because there are at least 2 dominant reactive parts, L & C where the inductance and capacitance is probably the series wire length of your probe ground length and coaxial probe capacitance giving a sine wave around 30% of 40ns or 80MHz with a 10:1 probe.

Reduce the inductance length or adding series R to dampen the wave with Zc(f)=R would reduce the ringing.

But this as nothing to do with the question of course as I indicated in comments.